# Array pointer to 2d array c++

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have N number of 2d(column,row) arrays. Thus I am trying to create an array pointer of size N each pointing to the respective 2D array. The code goes like.

```
int col = 3,row = 2,N =2;
float blue[][row] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; // 2d array (for N=1)
float green[][row] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; // 2d array (for N=2)
float (*arry_ptr[N])[col][row]; // this works
```

---

```
arry_ptr[0]= &blue;  // trying to point the 1st pointer to 1st 2d array
arry_ptr[1]= &green;  // trying to point the 2nd pointer to 2nd 2d array
```

---

I know that the last two lines of code are not appropriate and it does throw error. Is there any solution to increment the pointer and make it point to the 2d arrays in sequential order and NOT like in the below line.

```
float (*arry_ptr[N]) ={a,b}  // this works but i can allocate only single 2d array at a time.
```

Comment: What makes you think those 2 lines are inappropriate and what error are you getting? Only problem I can see here is that with `col` and `row` as regular variables, you force the arrays to become VLAs, and VLAs cannot be initialized. And if you wish to use VLAs, you should have tagged this C not C++.

Comment: Having N as int and not const int is a bad idea while using as array size during initialisation

Answer (score 1):

First of all C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), so technically your code is not legal. The dimension needs to be compile-time constants.

Secondly, if it was me I would use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, and using type-aliases. Something like this:

```
using array_type = std::array<std::array<float, 2>, 3>;

array_type blue = { ... }
array_type green = { ... }

array_type &array_refs[] = { blue, green };
```

Potentially, depending on what the `blue` and `green` arrays are used for, I would rather use a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) instead of a nested array. So like this instead:

```
using array_type = std::array<std::pair<float, float>, 3>;
```

Or even structures instead.

Comment: I have totally 100 2d arrays not just blue and green, it was just for example. This is not a place for structures..

Comment: @user3581370 You might want to stop and think about your design a little. Having that many fixed arrays is going to be a maintenance nightmare. Maybe you should think about auto-generating them, either at compile time or once at run-time?

Comment: @user3581370 Besides that, you might still consider the rest of my answer, at the very least the part about using type-aliases (`using` or `typedef`).

Answer (score 1):

Now i don't get any error at the last two lines. I just changed it to constant integers as i am using fixed size.. Dint oversee it .

```
const int col = 3,row = 2,N =2;
float blue[][row] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; // 2d array (for N=1)
float green[][row] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; // 2d array (for N=2)
float (*arry_ptr[N])[col][row]; 
arry_ptr[0]= &blue;  // trying to point the 1st pointer to 1st 2d array
arry_ptr[1]= &green;  // trying to point the 2nd pointer to 2nd 2d array
```

Cheers,
LAKSHMI

Answer (score 0):

C++ is tagged so,

For doing this " float (*arry_ptr[N]) ={a,b} ". I would recommend to use structures than plain array.

Struct {  float a,b}; // after this u can do .